# Creating module manager using Python?

Tags: python, irc, bots

I am building an IRC bot using Python. I require the bot to be extendable, and am looking to build a module system that checks modules and registers them on the fly, when the bot is running. E.g., someone with enough access could send something like "module enable feedparse" on IRC, which would search for the feedparse module in the modules/ directory. If it's there, get the full name, version and description of the module from global variables in the module itself. Then it registers and enables the module on the spot.

How would I go about doing this? Thanks!

Comment: This question is rather vague.  You want to "check modules", and "register them on the fly".  I've got no idea what it means to "check" a module, nor do I know what you mean by "registering".  Maybe all your are looking for is [`__import__()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#__import__)?

Comment: By checking, I mean checking that required functions for the bot to be "registered" are present in the module. And by registering, I mean import them, and I guess "inject" the triggers etc. to the bot so that the module comes into effect immediately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally have done the following, create a manager for your modules, then run your modules as completely separate processes.

- That way reloading a process is as simple as killing and running it
- shutting down and starting is simple
- and so is error handling because you can just pipe stderr to the irc
  channel.
- You also have the advantage of being able to load new modules without halting the bot or fighting pythons import mechanics

Its much better to use this "hypervisor" design than to worry about module reloading or other methods of doing the same goal. It also dodges the hot code reloading problem that can happen in python.

Much of the above can be achieved with just [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) or the [multiprocess](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing.html) module if you want to get truly fancy

Comment: But how is the subprocess meant to communicate with the main script? i.e. handling triggers, sending status messages to the terminal. The "hypervisor" design would work more efficient for me as far as I can see.

Comment: You just feed input down the pipe and read off the output, its up to you how you want to implement that

Comment: Well, how would I use multiprocessing? Any relatively easy tutorial other than the Python docs?

Comment: Sorry I really don't have the time to go into depth, write your plugins as separate programs, either open sockets, memory mapped or shared data structures then let them spin on there own, for this I used redis, every program had its own "queue" so one plugin could do redis.rpop("timePlugin:inbound") -> blocks until it gets something, processes the plugin then slaps it on "timePlugin:outbound", afterwards the client simply loops over its plugin keys getting everything and slapping it out to the channel, you can have dedicated or non dedicated channels to listen too as well. Hmm let me code this

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9017/discussion-between-fike-and-jakob-bowyer)